# Angular: variable is not updated after subscribing

Tags: angular

I have a service, that returns `Observables<SubscriberModel[]>`.

```
export interface SubscriberModel {
    email: string;
}
```

in my component I get subscribers$ in constructor:

```
public subscribers$: Observable<SubscriberModel[]>;
this.subscribers$ = this.subscribersService.getAll();
```

and show their in template:

```
<p *ngFor="let subscriber of subscribers$ | async">{{subscriber.email}}</p>
<button (click)="onDownloadClick()">
    <a [href]="fileUrl" download="file.txt">DownloadFile</a>
</button>
```

I have to download my subscribers into file:

```
public data: any;

public onDownloadClick(): void {
    this.subscribers$.pipe(
        map(res => res.map(i => i.email)),
    )
        .subscribe(res => {
            console.log(res) //array of string
            this.data = res;
        });

    console.log(this.data); //undefined
    const blob: Blob =
        new Blob([this.data], {type: 'application/octet-stream'});

    this.fileUrl =
        this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(window.URL.createObjectURL(blob));
}
```

Why in console.log `this.data` is undefined?

Comment: Observables work asynchronously. Therefore the code following your subscription runs before the subscription finishes.

Comment: Tell me please, how can I fix that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

put your process related service's subscribe's inside. Async functions doesn't stop another process. So code goes on with next line while it is still executed. so outside of async function may not read data due to response of server.

```
public onDownloadClick(): void {
   this.subscribers$.pipe( map(res => res.map(i => i.email)),)
   .subscribe(res => {
       console.log(res) //array of string
       this.data = res;
       console.log(this.data); //undefined
       const blob: Blob = new Blob([res], {type: 'application/octet-stream'});       
       this.fileUrl = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(window.URL.createObjectURL(blob));
    });

}
```

Comment: In this case file.txt have an html, not subscribers email value

Comment: Observables work asynchronously so it doesn't matter where data comes. You need to take inside subscribe

Comment: It works correct only if I pass res  
`const blob: Blob = new Blob([res]], {type: 'application/octet-stream'});  ` inside subscribe

Comment: if u directly assign res to blob then you don't need to assignt to this.data

Comment: oh, sorry, with res I have the same problems. The value of file is correct only after the second button click(

Comment: put ngIf to button if fileUrl filled That can be sync problem too. Second can work because while you click second time it filled. You should hide button until href filled

Comment: when I click on the button for the first time, the file contains html, and the second time and subsequent ones - the necessary information

Comment: Yes , because for first time it is empty then not download anything . I suggest you to use filesaver plugin easy to add project and use

Comment: in my case there is no better solution than the plugin?

Comment: You can fill url witout clicking while ngOnInit or in constructor  and remove onclick just stay jus a element tah in html .

Comment: Thank you so much for your answers, I use filesaver plugin and it works good for me :)

Comment: You’re welcome :) .That is common plugin to use to file download

Answer (score 2):

`this.data` is assigned data asynchronously. As such, all the dependent statements must be inside the subscription. So the `console.log` should be inside the subscription

```js
public data: any;

public onDownloadClick(): void {
  this.subscribers$.pipe(
    map(res => res.map(i => i.email)),
  )
  .subscribe(res => {
    console.log(res) //array of string
    this.data = res;
    console.log(this.data);
    const blob: Blob = new Blob([this.data], {type: 'application/octet-stream'});
    this.fileUrl = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(window.URL.createObjectURL(blob));
  });
}
```

More info on accessing asynchronous data: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14220323/6513921

Comment: But in this case value in file.txt is undefined and only if I click the second time to download button, the file includes correct value

Comment: The other statements were also dependent on the async data. They should be moved inside the subscription as well. I've updated the answer.